# retrieve data json from inlocalstorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Problem retrieving data from json stored in localStorage

```
{
    "resta": [
        {
            "id": "5",
            "nombre": "Creperia",
            "categoria": "Restaurantes",
            "imagen": "13641634852407.jpg",
            "telefono": "123456789",
            "descripcion": "El mejor sitio en el centro...",
            "direccion": "Calle de los refuiados",
            "dto": "50"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "nombre": "Rosada",
            "categoria": "Restaurantes",
            "imagen": "13574873327231.jpg",
            "telefono": "23476580",
            "descripcion": "Somos una taquería ...",
            "direccion": "via quiensabe ",
            "dto": "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have dealt with:

```
jspa = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cercanos'));
$.each(jspa.resta, function(k, v) {
  $('#lista').append(v.nombre+' '+v.categoria+' '+v.descripcion);
});
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"resta":[{"id":"126","nombre":"Creperia",...
```

¿What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you storing it in the localStorage? Can you share that bit as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called each on `object` not on `array`. Your `array` is `jspa.resta`.

Try this:

```
jspa = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cercanos'));
$.each(jspa.resta, function(k, v) {
  $('#lista').append(v.nombre+' '+v.categoria+' '+v.descripcion);
});
```

Also check is `JSON.parse` parsed your data correctly.